# Is being defiled from committing moral and sexual sins a physical defilement or spiritual defilement?

Tags: holy

Reference Leviticus 18:20, 23 and Mark 7:21-23. Is there any distinction of defilement or are there specific types of defilement (e.g. ceremonial)?

Comment: The Bible and Torah make no such distinction between physical and spiritual defilement.

Comment: _Flee fornication. Every sin that a man doeth is without the body; but he that committeth fornication sinneth ***against his own body***._ 1 Corinthians 6:18.

Comment: @Dottard... the Torah does make a distinction in that the punishment or requirement for ritual defilement is minor, often involving simply being rendered "unclean" until evening or needing to bathe. The punishment for moral sins is sometimes very harsh indeed.  Ritual defilement, in fact, was not necessarily a sin - as in the case of childbirth or menstruation. As "sin offering" was required as a preventative measure, to ensure that the person entering the Temple area would not "defile" it.

Comment: @DanFefferman - moral lapse does not involve uncleanness and thus is a different matter under Torah.

Answer (score 1):

Moral or sexual sin is a spiritual defilement, not a physical or ceremonial. Ceremonial category is a very distinct one, comprising the ancient cultural hygienic tradition. This [gotquestions](https://www.gotquestions.org/ceremonially-unclean.html) article on ceremonial uncleanness explains well:

> Some practices that caused a person to become ceremonially unclean
> included the following:
>
> 1. Childbirth (Leviticus 12:1–2, 5)
> 2. Infectious diseases, like leprosy (Leviticus 13:9–11)
> 3. Unusual bodily discharges (Leviticus 15:2–15)
> 4. Bodily discharges related to reproduction—e.g., a man’s emission of semen (Leviticus 15:16–18) and a woman’s menstrual cycle (Leviticus
>    15:19–30)
> 5. Touching a corpse (Numbers 19:11)
> 6. Handling the ashes of a red heifer used in the water of cleansing (Numbers 19:1–10)
> 7. Contact with anyone or anything that was unclean (Leviticus 5:3)
>
> Some of the laws related to ceremonial uncleanness seem related to
> public health and hygiene, such as the laws addressing skin diseases,
> mold growth, and bodily discharges. Understanding there was a
> distinction between “the holy and the common, between the unclean and
> the clean” (Leviticus 10:10) not only set the Israelites apart from
> other nations, but it served as a visceral reminder of God’s holiness
> and mankind’s sin. Ceremonial uncleanness made a person realize he
> needed cleansing and purification to approach the Lord. Unclean
> Israelites were separated from the temple worship for a time, a symbol
> of their spiritual uncleanness before God. To be clean, they had to
> wait a period of time, wash, and, most of the time, offer sacrifices
> (Numbers 19:11–12; Leviticus 14:19).
>
> In the New Testament, the Pharisees were scrupulous in making
> distinctions between unclean and clean, but they missed the heart of
> God’s commands. For instance, the Pharisees placed a major emphasis on
> ceremonial washing before meals, and they openly rebuked Jesus’
> disciples for not cleansing themselves in this way (Matthew 15:2; Mark
> 7:2–4). Jesus responded to the rebuke by announcing to the crowd that
> “a man is not defiled by what enters his mouth, but by what comes out
> of it” (Matthew 15:11, BSB).

Answer (score 0):

The background of Mark 7:21-23 was Jesus rebuked the Pharisees, He said

> 8 You have let go of the commands of God and are holding on to human traditions.” (Mark 7:8 NIV)

What Jesus meant was the Pharisees, who were the teachers of the law, took the law literally that sin happened only when there was physically happening as in Leviticus 18:20-23. But Jesus proclaimed, even it happened in their mind, they already sinned (Mark 7:21-23).

Therefore no matter a sin is physical (happened) or spiritual (motive), it is still a sin, and the consequence is the same, losing the grace from God.